# aggregate in new columns using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `pandas` dataframe:

```
    time  mes   mech
0   1     50    A
1   2     15    A
2   3     16    A
3   1     17    B
4   2     49    B
5   3     62    B
```

I would like to aggregate it by `time` and then have the renamed columns for each `mech`, like so:

```
    time  mes_A mes_B
0   1     50    17
1   2     15    49
2   3     16    62
```

what's the best way to do this?

Comment: `df.pivot('time', 'mech', 'mes').reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

```
out = (df.pivot('time', 'mech', 'mes')
         .add_prefix('mech_')
         .reset_index())
out.columns.name = None
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   time  mech_A  mech_B
0     1      50      17
1     2      15      49
2     3      16      62
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], "mes": [50, 15, 16, 17, 49, 62], "mech": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]})


def agg_mech(row):
    return {f"mech_{v}": v for v in row}

df2 = df.groupby("time").agg({"mes": "first", "mech": agg_mech})
df2 = df2.merge(df2.mech.apply(pd.Series), left_index=True, right_index=True).drop(columns=["mech"])
```